# Modifying IQueryable like a Reference Type doesn't work?

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

It's common in C# to modify objects in private methods as they are commonly reference-types instead of value types, for example:

```
public void Main()
{
    var person = new Person();

    SetPersonsName(person);

    System.Writeln(person.Firstname + " " + person.Lastname);
}

private void SetPersonsName(Person person)
{
    person.Firstname = "Jimi";
    person.Lastname = "Hendrix";
}
```

Firstname and Lastname are applied to the object and will be correctly printed as we pass in the object by reference (pointer to it's location in memory) rather than creating a copy of the object like we'd do for value-types.

So what if we have an IQueryable and which to use the same approach to add Where clauses to the object collection, like below?

```
public void Main()
{
    // Returns Jimi Hendrix and Justin Bieber
    var people = _workspace.GetDataSource<Person>();

    FilterByRockGods(people);

    foreach(var person in people)
    {
        // Will still print "Jimi Hendrix" and "Justin Bieber"
        // Should only print "Jimi Hendrix" (obviously)
        System.Writeln(person.Firstname + " " + person.Lastname);
    }
}

private void FilterByRockGods(IQueryable<Person> people)
{
    people = people.Where(x => x.IsRockGod);
}
```

This won't work, the Where clause applied in the private method is not applied to the collection

You have to do the following instead:

```
public void Main()
{
    // Returns Jimi Hendrix and Justin Bieber
    var people = _workspace.GetDataSource<Person>();

    people = FilterByRockGods(people);

    foreach(var person in people)
    {
        // Prints "Jimi Hendrix"
        System.Writeln(person.Firstname + " " + person.Lastname);
    }
}

private IQueryable<Person> FilterByRockGods(IQueryable<Person> people)
{
    people = people.Where(x => x.IsRockGod);

    return people;
}
```

Why is this?

Comment: You might observe the same thing about `string` - methods that suggest they modify the string instead return a *new* string that represents the altered state. Or any class which has been designed to be immutable but has methods suggesting change.

Comment: In your method `FilterByRockGods` you are only setting an expression, the expression is not "applied" until the collection is enumerated, the fact that you are passing the the collection to a method is not relevent, you get this behaviour however you do it, it is called deferred execution.

Comment: @BenRobinson deferred execution isn't the issue here, regardless of when the collection is enumerated, the .Where clause in the private method is not applied to the expression in the calling scope.  As Damien says, the issue is that is creates new new expression, so modifying it like a reference-type will not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because when you write `person.Firstname = ...` you are invoking the `FirstName`'s property setter which alters the instance's data.

`Where`, in contrast does not alter the `IEnumerable` it's called on but produces a new `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Thank you; does this make IQueryable a value-type or is there another term for this behaviour in this context?

Comment: It does not make it a value type. If IQueryable had a 'Name' property for instance with a setter, you would be able to execute 'people.Name = "Doctor Fred"'.

Comment: So is the problem that the method `FilterByRocksGods()` is attempting to overwrite the pointer passed into it? Is  that what is not succeeding?

Comment: FilterByRocksGods is not overwriting anything. people is this method is a local variable which value you can change inside the method without affecting the variable passed by the caller.

Comment: `people = people.Where(x => x.IsRockGod);` sure *looks* like it's attempting to overwrite the parameter `people`. I guess it can't be succeeding since after the call to `FilterByRockGods()`, the original `IQueryable` is unmodified. So is the lesson here that when a parameter is passed by reference, the 'pointed-to' object's state can be changed, but the reference cannot be changed to point at something else?

Comment: It can if your use ref parameters

Comment: Crazy. I thought reference types were passed by reference by default. But they're not. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx. Thank you, vc 74.

Comment: They're not, even in C++ which is much less strict it's not the case.